# How to dismiss data before line.startswith

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file that looks like:

```
# Grace project file
#
@version 50005
@page size 600, 600
@default linewidth 2.5
@default linestyle 1
@default color 1
@default font 0
@default char size 1.2
@default symbol size 1.2
@g0 on
@target G0.S0
@type xy
 -0.108851E+02  0.127435E-03
 -0.108715E+02  0.127829E-03
 -0.108579E+02  0.128191E-03
 -0.108443E+02  0.128502E-03
 -0.108306E+02  0.128726E-03
 -0.108170E+02  0.128838E-03
 -0.108034E+02  0.128751E-03
&
@target G0.S1
@type xy
 -0.108851E+02  0.472694E-04
 -0.108715E+02  0.474233E-04
 -0.108579E+02  0.475837E-04
 -0.108443E+02  0.477448E-04
 -0.108306E+02  0.479052E-04
 -0.108170E+02  0.480669E-04
 -0.108034E+02  0.482279E-04
&
```

I am trying to read from `@target` line as:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
  q = 0
  for key,group in it.groupby(f,lambda line: line.startswith('@target')):
    x=[];y=[]
    if not key:
        group = list(group)
        group.pop(0)
        group.pop(-1)
        # print(len(group))
        for i in range(len(group)):
          x.append(group[i].split()[0])
          y.append(group[i].split()[1])
        filen[q]=np.array(list(map(list,zip(x,y))),dtype=float)
```

The problem is, it is still reading the lines before the match and giving error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rudra/splitagr.py", line 47, in <module>
    filen[q]=np.array(list(map(list,zip(x,y))),dtype=float)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '@page'
```

I thought the `groupby` will start matching **after** the `line.startswith(@target)`, but then how that `@page` is coming, I have no idea. If I manually delete everything before the `@target` line, it works fine.

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

You can narrow the file down to only those lines after `@target` by using something like the following:

```
pos = 0
with open('filename', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
        if '@target' in line:
            pos = idx + 1
            break
    lines = lines[pos:]
```

or more simply:

```
with open('filename', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if '@target' not in line:
            continue
        # Found '@target' rest of logic.
```

Hope that helps!